# cannot unpack non-iterable int object creating shop and cart in Django with session

Tags: python, django, session

I am creating a store and when executing this address http://127.0.0.1:8000/carro/agregar/3/ it has to load the product in the store widget where the cart is. If the car is not in the session, create it. Tried deleting cookies and nothing. But when I press the buy button on any product, in this case on product 3, the button sends to the correct address but the page gives me the following error

> TypeError at /carro/agregar/3/ cannot unpack non-iterable int object
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/carro/agregar/3/ Django Version: 4.0.4 Exception
> Type: TypeError Exception Value: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
> Exception Location:
> C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py,
> line 1374, in build_filter Python Executable:
> C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe Python
> Version: 3.10.4

and this

> C:\Users\HP\Documents\ProyectosDjango\ProyectoWeb\carro\views.py, line
> 8, in agregar_producto
>
> producto = Producto.objects.get(producto_id)

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .carro import Carro
from tienda.models import Producto

# Create your views here.
def agregar_producto(request, producto_id):
    carro= Carro(request)
    producto = Producto.objects.get(producto_id)
    carro.agregar(producto=producto)
    return redirect('Tienda')

def eliminar_producto(request, producto_id):
    carro= Carro(request)
    producto = Producto.objects.get(producto_id)
    carro.eliminar(producto=producto)
    return redirect('Tienda')

def restar_producto(request, producto_id):
    carro= Carro(request)
    producto = Producto.objects.get(producto_id)
    carro.restar(producto=producto)
    return redirect('Tienda')

def limpiar_carro(request):
    carro= Carro(request)
    carro.limpiar_carro()
    return redirect('Tienda')
```

context_processor.py

```
def importe_total_carro(request):
    total = 0
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        for key, value in request.session["carro"].items():
            

            total = total +(float(value['precio'])*value['cantidad'])
    return {'importe_total_carro':total}
```

urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name= "carro"
urlpatterns = [  
    path('agregar/<int:producto_id>/', views.agregar_producto, name="agregar"),  
    path('eliminar/<int:producto_id>/', views.eliminar_producto, name="eliminar"),  
    path('restar/<int:producto_id>/', views.restar_producto, name="restar"),  
    path('limpiar/>', views.limpiar_carro, name="limpiar"),  
]
```

carro.py (classes)

```
class Carro:
    def __init__(self,request):
        self.request=request
        self.session=request.session
        carro = self.session.get("carro")
        if not carro:
            carro=self.session["carro"]={}
            self.session.modified = True
        #else:
        self.carro = carro
    def agregar(self, producto):
        print('Estos son los datos {} => {}'.format(self, producto))
        if (str(producto.id) not in self.carro.keys()):
            self.carro[producto.id]={
                "producto.id":producto.id,
                "nombre":producto.nombre,
                "precio":str(producto.precio),
                "cantidad":1,
                "imagen":producto.imagen.url
            }
        else:
            for key, value in self.carro.items():
                if key == str(producto.id):
                    value["cantidad"] =  value["cantidad"] +1
                    break
        self.guardar_carro()
    
    def guardar_carro(self):
        self.session["carro"] = self.carro
        self.session.modified = True
    
    def eliminar(self, producto):
        producto.id= str(producto.id)
        if producto.id in self.carro.keys():
            del self.carro[producto.id]
            self.guardar_carro()

    def restar_producto(self,producto):
        for key, value in self.carro.items():
            if key == str(producto.id):
                value["cantidad"] =  value["cantidad"] - 1
                if value["cantidad"] < 1:
                    self.eliminar(producto)
                break
            self.guardar_carro()

    def limpiar_carro(self):
        self.session["carro"]={}
        self.session.modified = True
```

tienda.html

```
{% extends "ProyectoWebApp/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div style="float:right; margin-left: 10px;">
    
    {% include "carro/widget.html" %}
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
  {% for Prod in productos %}
    <div class="col-sm-4" > <!--style="padding: 10px; -->
      <div class="card" style="width: 15rem;margin: 5px 5px;"> <!--style="padding: 10px; -->
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{Prod.imagen.url}}" height="160px" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{Prod.nombre}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{Prod.precio}}</p>
          <a href="{% url 'carro:agregar' Prod.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">comprar</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

widget carrito

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="color:white">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3" class="tex-center">
            Carro compras
        </th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Producto</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Suma</th>

    </tr>


</thead>
<tbody>
    {% if request.session.carro.items %}
        {% for key,value in request.session.carro.items %}
            <tr class="text-center">
                <td>{{value.nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{value.cantidad}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{% url 'carro:agregar' value.producto_id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-succes">+</a>
                    <a href="{% url 'carro:restar' value.producto_id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">-</a><br>
                    $ {{value.precio}} 
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div class="alert alert-danger text=center" >Carro Vacio</div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    {% endif %}
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            > Total: {{importe_total_carro}}

        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

models.py

```
from http.client import PRECONDITION_FAILED
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class CategoriaProd(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'categoriaProd'
        verbose_name_plural= 'categoriasProd'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
    
class Producto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    precio = models.FloatField()
    imagen =models.ImageField(upload_to='tienda', null=True, blank=True)
    categorias = models.ForeignKey(CategoriaProd, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    disponibilidad = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'producto'
        verbose_name_plural= 'productos'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just pass a single integer positional argument to the `get` or `filter` functions, you need to pass keyword arguments where the key is the name of the field you want to filter on.

If you are passing the `id` of the instance then use "id" as your keyword argument

```
producto = Producto.objects.get(id=producto_id)
```